# FB.api("/me/likes") Different results with admin userID admin and others userID

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having a problem with return if user has liked a certain page.

If I try it with my admin userID

```
FB.api("/me/likes/259239627467123",.. return correct: [Object { category="Travel/leisure", name="KatkaFodor Bt.", created_time="2014-07-10T13:33:54+0000", ...}]
```

But if I have another userID `FB.api("/me/likes/259239627467123",.. return empty data: Array[0]`

Where is my problem?

```
var token='';

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '1506526099561855', // App ID
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
          scope: 'user_likes',
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            console.log("Token:"+response.authResponse.accessToken);
            console.log("User ID:"+response.authResponse.userID);

            token=response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api(
                "/me/likes/259239627467123",
                function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        console.log(response);
                        /* handle the result */
                        console.log("User likey!");
                        //document.getElementById('nolikey').style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        console.log("User no likey :("+response.error.message);
                    }
                }
                ,{access_token: token});
        });

};
// Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));


function Login()
{
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) 
            {
                getUserInfo();
            }
            else 
            {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
         },{scope: 'email,user_likes'});

}

function getUserInfo()
{
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(response);

    var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
      str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
      str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
      str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "user_likes" permission has to get approved by the Facebook team in order to be available for users who are not app admins.

See the Changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog